# "Too many open files" at MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I make thousands of requests to SQL Server. Usually they are good. But, sometimes, I have this message:

Too many open files. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Then it goes good immediately in next requests. Sometimes I have few such messages in row, sometimes only one per thousands requests.

Is there some setting on the SQL Server itself I have to increase to get rid of this **Too many open files** issue?

Comment: The same issue for me, I'm using end-task and reopen SSMS.

Comment: This is server application which gets data from SQL Server, I cannot restart it. It uses  Java Connection Pool and it actually works fine after this error. It just that few requests are missed. Which is unacceptable for serious app.

Comment: The problem lies within your application, not sql server. No one can debug your code without seeing how you handle your connection but that handling is the most likely culprit.

Comment: I agree when I develop my app. But when development is done and it is doing everyday job and job is exactly the same (in my case it is simple query as simple as "select id from account where account_number=:account_number" and this query ran thousands times before and after and, BTW, with the same account_number successfully then, I think, it is SQL Server issue.